# Iphone and right-to-left text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, uitextview

How can I display RTL text(e.g. arabic) in UITextView?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i got it right. The simulator version in my xcode was set to 2.2 :S

It's working perfect after I select 3.0.

Cheers!