# How to force a piece of text to be 'direction ltr' inside a 'direction rtl' paragraph

Tags: html, css, multilingual, bidi

So, phone numbers are always ltr (left to right).

Working on a multilingual website I need to insert a phone number (with a '+' prefix and numbers separated by '-') inside a text paragraph that has direction rtl (for relevant languages of course)

So I have something like this:

```css
.ltr #test {direction:ltr}
.rtl #test {direction:rtl}
#phone {direction:ltr}
```

```html
<div class="ltr"><p id="test">Please call to <span id="phone">+44-123-321</span> for some help.</p></div>
<div class="rtl"><p id="test">Please call to <span id="phone">+44-123-321</span> for some help.</p></div>
```

Of course this is not working because '`direction`' only works for block elements and '`span`' is an inline element. I need the phone number to be inside the paragraph so I can't change '`span`' to '`display:inline`'

I'm being clear?

How to make it work?

Comment: RTL algorithms normally take numbers into account, so you don't need to do anything for numbers to be rendered correctly, regardless of `LTR` or `RTL` of the container. Are you actually seeing this issue or simply trying to preempt?

Comment: @Oded: I'm seeing it. I think because of the '+' and '-' between numbers its just confusing the algorithm...

Comment: In Arabic at least, the + sign should go to the left of a phone number, just like it does in English. Type out the phone number just like you would in English, first type the `+` character, then the first number from the left, then the second number from the left, and so on. You may be trying to fix something which isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a unicode directionality marker character just before the `+` sign to give the algorithm the hint it needs.

These are:

```
LTR: 0x200E
RTL: 0x200F
```

So:

```html
<p id="text">Please call to <span id="phone">&#x200F;+44-123-321</span> for some help</p>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182962/rtl-shows-numbers-at-the-end-of-lines) SO answer for more details.

Comment: I tested this and can confirm it to work, however in HTML notation it will be `&#x200E;` and `&#x200F;`.

Comment: @nikc - Well spotted. Updated HTML.

Comment: YOU'RE THE BEST!

Comment: You may also use `&rlm;` and `&lrm;` in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 36):

Try adding `#phone {direction:ltr; display:inline-block}`

Comment: `Because HTML UAs can turn off CSS styling, we recommend HTML authors to use the HTML dir attribute and <bdo> element to ensure correct bidirectional layout in the absence of a style sheet. Authors should not use direction in HTML documents.` Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#direction

Answer (score 15):

Another option could be to use `dir='ltr'` attribute, in your inline element:

```
<p id="text">Please call to <span dir='ltr'>+44-123-321</span> for some help</p>
```

Please note that including `&#x200E;` in your HTML is as bad as using `dir='ltr'` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solutions won't work if the first character is an LTR character.

```html
<span dir="ltr">&lrm;א + ב = ג</span>
```

You can force it with `&#x202D;` ([LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Overrides))

```html
<span>&#x202D;א + ב = ג</span>
```

or by using css `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`

```html
<span style="unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">א + ב = ג</span>
```