# How to keep direction of a block even language changed

Tags: css, direction

The original code is English

```
    direction: ltr;
```

but when i change language to arabic the code changes to

```
    direction: rtl;
```

I want all website to be changed from ltr to rtl but I don't want some specific blocks to be changed from ltr to rtl.
please give me suggestions
and I have searched but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325660/how-to-force-a-piece-of-text-to-be-direction-ltr-inside-a-direction-rtl-para) is not correct answer because i want to make changes in css file not in other files.
[code for language direction changes css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJXUt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using different blocks with different id/class

and assign direction for the required block

Comment: how can i change id/class when the language is changed?

Comment: assign classes in such a way that they depend on the direction

for example english: left to right
Arab: right to left

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the style to the specific div with direction should fix the issue:

```
.the_required_block{
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Also, considering that you have the div `.ab__deal_of_the_day{}` for `rtl;` you might need to do the following fix for specificiation:

```
.ab__deal_of_the_day .the_required_block{
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Cheers!