# Right to left UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel, right-to-left

I need to display a text using a UILabel ( can't use UIWebView ), and it sometimes contains both Hebrew and English. using UILabel's default settings the sentence gets mixed up and doesn't make sense. I have failed to found a way to make UILabel display text rtl.

Does anybody know anyway to do that, or a code that implements this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182962/rtl-shows-numbers-at-the-end-of-lines), it contains some info on this subject that might help you out.
It seems to work for some by adding the code \u200F to the strings to be displayed.

```
NSString *RTFstr = "1. בבוקר"; //This could be any right-to-left string
NSString *directionalString = [@"\u200F" stringByAppendingString:[note text]];
[someUITextView setString:directionalString];
```

Comment: It worked but "\u200F" is showing , how we can remove this without affecting string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743688/left-to-right-mark-not-working-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
-(void)fnForWritingDirection:(UILabel*)label textFor:(NSString *)stringForText{

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [stringForText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

    [paragraphStyle setBaseWritingDirection:NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft];

    [attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];

    label.attributedText=attrStr;

}
```