# Iphone right to left displaying

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I am working on an arabic iphone application and I don't know how to display table view and other staff from right to left, any help please?

Comment: Provide detail information of your Problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right to left UILabels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595466/right-to-left-uilabels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7595883/834998) for how to display right to left text in a `UILabel`, which is the label class that is used throughout Cocoa touch, including in `UITableView` cells. You can create the right-to-left string like this (copy & pasted from linked answer):

```
NSString *str = "1. בבוקר"; //This could be any right-to-left string
NSString *directionalString = [@"\u200F" stringByAppendingString:str];
```

The unicode character U+200F is an invisible character that indicates the direction of the text, so you can use it at the start of the string to indicate that the text is right-to-left. Then, you can assign the string to wherever:

```
cell.textLabel.text = directionalString;
```