# Left-To-Right Mark not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

I'm trying to use [LRM](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) in order to make a string properly displays in arabic. My string is as follows:

> Percentage is: 32.12%

However on arabic it displayed as:

> %32.12 :نسبة ط

So far so good. On objective-c I've used in the past following markup to fix this problem:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u200E %@", value]
```

But when I try it on Swift it just didn't move the percent:

```
"\u{200E}\(value)"
```

Am I using unicode characters wrong in Swift or I made mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Edit question with your swift code .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below should be a comment on the question, really, but I need the formatting...

I do this in a Playground (Xcode 7 beta 4)

```
let value = "32.12%"
print("نسبة ط:\u{200E}\(value)")
```

And it prints

```
32.12% :نسبة ط
```

Is that what you want?

Also

```
let value = "\u{200E}32.12%"
print("نسبة ط:\(value)")
```

works the same.  This is in the Playground.  Are you using an older version of Xcode perhaps?

Comment: So sorry for the stupid mistake I did. I was putting unicode character on the wrong label :) I'm giving you the upvote and accept as it is the correct way to handle it anyway. For the record I'm using Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Thanks for that not totally deserved accept.  No mistake is stupid until you do it twice.